# I installed nvidia drivers without opengl library, how to know if they are working?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, gpu

I just installed nvidia drivers without opengl libraries and rebooted but nvidia-detector returns none. How to know if the drivers are working ?

**Updated:**

nvidia-settings return this on console:

```
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
   have been installed along with this driver at
   /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
   application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
   prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
   Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

and the settings window open up with this dialog:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.
Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root),
and restart the X server.
```

but I don't want to use the gpu as VGA Controller because the system already have integrated controller.

I want to use the gpu only for accelerated compute provided by cuda

Comment: nvidia-settings     ..... launch that ... another one is ...  nvidia-smi

Comment: @ScottStensland please review, I've updated the question